# strtok() very weird behaviour

Tags: c

**EDIT: new problem**

```
    char * symbolInList = listOfSymbolTokens[0];
    char * addressOfSymbol = listOfSymbolTokens[1];

    printf("symbolLookingFor: %s\n", symbolLookingFor);
    printf("symbolInList: %s\n", symbolInList);
    printf("addressOfSymbol: %s\n", addressOfSymbol);
    if (strcmp(symbolInList, symbolLookingFor) == 0) {
        strcpy(tokenAddress, addressOfSymbol);
        return;
    }
    printf("did not enter for loop\n");
```

For some reason, strcmp(symbolinList, symbolLookingFor) does not return 0 even when they are the same.

```
symbolLookingFor: abc
symbolInList: abc
addressOfSymbol: 3011

did not enter for loop
```

it does not enter the if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong

```
const char sdilem[1] = " ";
```

To store a `" "` string you need at least 2 characters in the buffer. (In C this is not an error.)

Firstly, to avoid such mistakes you don't need to specify the size explicitly

```
const char sdilem[] = " ";
```

Secondly, in this case you could just use

```
const char *sdilem = " ";
```

Comment: Why does it work when the three letter word does not start with a or b? If sdilem didnt have enough memory then why does it work at all?

Comment: @yanhua: Undefined behavior is undefined. Anything is possible. It could simply depend on the garbage (or not-so-garbage) content of the adjacent memory.

Comment: thanks for that, got a new problem now if you could take a look at it, edited in main post

Comment: fixed it - was a newline character!

Comment: @yanhua Don't edit an existing question to ask something new.  Leave it the way it was so _other people_ can see the answered question, and open a new question.